# Java SWT Spinner won't auto resize based on user's entries

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, spinner

So I am working with java SWT spinner, but my issue is that when the number is more than one digit i.e. higher than 10, the spinner does not get bigger to contain the two digits or more. Therefore, the user is unable to see the number that he entered. Do you know how to make it auto-resize and refresh its size switch to the user entry and the size of the number ?

EDIT : Code used :

```
acquisitionTime = new Spinner(container, SWT.BORDER);
    acquisitionTime.setEnabled(true);
    acquisitionTime.setMinimum(1);
```

Thanks for your help
Peace

Comment: What kind of layout are you using?

Comment: Hello I have edited my question to include the code that I have used.

Comment: PS : I have used Grid data and added as a layoutData to my Spinner, however it got bigger in size but static sitll. It just didn't provide me with what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after several attempts ..I will post this to be a future reference for anyone who will have this issue. So basically what I did is I added a ModifyListener to my spinner, inside the modifyText method (I know I have numbers not text but it works just fine for numbers don't worry :D ), I took my composite(where I am defining the spinner) and I made somposite.layout(true). This will refresh the composite and thus the spinner will autoresize based on the new value. N.B. : don't forget to add a layout for your composite (I didn't specify one for my spinner) otherwise that won't work.

Have a good day :D